# How to optimize the request time for large data response?

Tags: web-applications, data, optimization, time-management

I have created a dashboard for rendering a list of clients into a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/). Below shown is the data model structure:
[image: data_model_structure]

When I had a few records in the clients schema, let's say a thousand rows, the request time was fairly okay. It would take around of 4-5 seconds for the whole trip, from requesting to processing at backend to sending response with data and rendering it to frontend. Once the data reached to 10,000+ rows, the time it's taking is too much. Now it takes anywhere near 17 seconds or sometimes even more. I'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), the [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) of this framework brings the data from the related tables (which is highly useful) but as the data is growing it's increasing the requesting time. My question is what could be a better approach to minimize the request time? How can I decrease the time it takes to request??

Comment: A very good rule of thumb I was given by my UX team at a previous role: if there's more than 20 results, nobody cares. I can't see any reason at all to request 17k records.

Comment: Besides what Philip has said, from the technical point of view, you are likely suffering from N+1 select issue if you are loading data using ORM, which is only going to get worse as your data grows. The only sensible solution for that is to rewrite your read layer using a different loading mechanism.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the reason I was requesting all the data at once is I'm creating DataTable rows for each row from database. Then it's initializing the datatable object for rendering first 10 rows and dividing remaining rows in components acting as pages. If I understand you correctly, I have to modify my whole requesting mechanism and implement ajax for sending requests via datatable and request a new set of data for each page created by the datatable plugin?

Comment: So you're fetching _seventeen thousand_ rows to show 10 of them? I think you've answered your own question as to how to speed this up.

Comment: @Andy come to think of it, you might be right. I'm not explicitly causing N+1 selecting problem, but the eloquent relationship of Laravel is. I do need to rewrite my reading layer with a totally different requesting approach.

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes, you can say that. But, I'm doing this because the js plugin I mentioned (DataTable) reads the whole HTML table structure which is creating through those rows of data and then initialize it's own structure dividing it into several pages. That way once the data is loaded, there is no more loading time if you navigate to other pages of data.

Comment: @Saud you need to only request the data for that particular page when that page loads. When the next page is requested, you then load that page from the database and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are the following two approaches for such scenarios:

- reduce the overall amount of data which is transferred to the client (this is what  Philip Kendall suggested in the comments)
- make the data request asynchronous and return the results in batches or pages

The first approach is most useful if you can tailor the data request directly to what your UI requires, since, as Philip already noted, it often does not make much sense to show 10k+ records directly within the UI, where each record is just an entry in a large list. For example, when data can be organized in a tree-like fashion, requesting only the tree level or subtree which is currently visible on the screen, there is no need to query the whole data at beforehand - it can often be requested on demand, for instance, when the user unfolds a certain subtree.

Unfortunately, there are also scenarios where getting those 10k+ records to the client first is necessary to allow things like interactive aggregation,  selection or smooth navigation on the client side. For this kind of scenario, the second approach can be more suitable. This, however, may require to reimplement the way the client deals with the data, and make it possible to work with a continously arriving stream of data.

I am not an expert on Laravel, but I guess Stackoverflow has all the technical details you may be looking for:

- [How can I make asynchronous request with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812632/how-can-i-make-asynchronous-request-with-laravel)
- [Best Practice for Laravel Asynchronous Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204673/best-practice-for-laravel-asynchronous-requests/46204855)